# How to optimize SQL query that uses GROUP BY and joined many-to-many relation tables?

Tags: sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have tables with many-to-many relations:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `size_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `size` (`size_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `items_styles` (
  `style_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`, `style_id`),
  INDEX `style` (`style_id`),
  INDEX `item` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `items_styles_item_id_item_id` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `items_themes` (
  `theme_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`, `theme_id`),
  INDEX `theme` (`theme_id`),
  INDEX `item` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `items_themes_item_id_item_id` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`)
);
```

I'm trying to get the report that shows `style_id` and the number of items that use this style but with applying filters to the `item` table and/or to another table, like this:

```
SELECT i_s.style_id, COUNT(i.id) total FROM item i
JOIN items_themes i_t ON i.id = i_t.item_id AND i_t.theme_id IN (6, 7)
JOIN items_styles i_s ON i.id = i_s.item_id
GROUP BY i_s.style_id;

-- or like this
SELECT i_s.style_id, COUNT(i.id) total FROM item i
JOIN items_themes i_t ON i.id = i_t.item_id AND i_t.theme_id IN (6, 7)
JOIN items_styles i_s ON i.id = i_s.item_id
WHERE i.size_id != 3
GROUP BY i_s.style_id;
```

[image]

[image]

The problem is that tables are pretty big so queries take a long time to execute (~8 seconds)

`item` - 8M rows
`items_styles` - 12M rows
`items_themes` - 11M rows

Is there any way to optimize these queries? If not, what approach can be used to receive such reports.
I will be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: What does [`EXPLAIN`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/explain/) have to say?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I've added EXPLAINs to the question.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need the `items` table for the queries.  Probably doesn't have much impact on performance, but no need.

So you can write the query as:

```
SELECT i_s.style_id, COUNT(*) as total
FROM items_themes i_t JOIN
     items_styles i_s 
     ON i_s.item_id = i_t.item_id
WHERE i_t.theme_id IN (6, 7)
GROUP BY i_s.style_id;
```

For this query, you want an index on `items_themes(theme_id, item_id)`.  There is no much you can do about the `GROUP BY`.

Then, I don't think this is what you really want, because it will double count an item that has both themes.  So, use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT i_s.style_id, COUNT(*) as total
FROM items_styles i_s          
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 
              FROM items_themes i_t
              WHERE i_t.item_id = i_s.item_id AND
                    i_t.theme_id IN (6, 7)
             )
GROUP BY i_s.style_id;
```

For this, you want an index on `items_themes(item_id, theme_id)`.  You can also try an index on `items_styles(style_id)`.  Some databases might be able to use that one, but I am guessing not MariaDB.

Comment: You have a typo in the first query here `COUNT(i.id)` but I got the idea. It's somewhat faster ~6sec. but still too slow. 2-3 sec. would be perfect :(
Second one has the same time as the one from my question.
Suggested indexes were added.
In some situations I have to use `item` table for filtering (see my second query).
Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @AleksandrUsarov . . . I am really surprised that the `EXISTS` version -- with the stated index -- offers no improvement on your current query.  Interesting.

Comment: idk what I'm doing wrong. I already have all indexes that you suggested to add.

Comment: @AleksandrUsarov . . . It doesn't mean you are doing anything wrong.  Data distributions play a large role in this.  My guess is that you have a lot of rows with "6"s and "7"s but not both.

Comment: yes, you're right, quite large amount of rows, 6 has ~2.6M rows. Despite the fact that I have little experience working with large data sets, it seems to me more and more that queries of this kind cannot be executed in real time and I need to pre-calculate and save in some aggregated table all possible variants.

Comment: @AleksandrUsarov . . . Your conclusion is probably correct.  Often, "historical" data is run on -- say -- a daily basis with more recent additions run if up-to-date data is needed.  Of course, triggers that maintain summary tables is another common solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a many-to-many table, it is optimal to have these two indexes:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`, `style_id`),
  INDEX `style` (`style_id`, `item_id`)
```

And be sure to use `InnoDB`.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Still, you have two many-to-many mappings, so there probably is no great solution.